# How to give alternating table rows different background colors in while loop and CSS (not using :nth-child() selector)

Tags: php, html, css, multiplication

I am trying to put background colors in a PHP while loop table with CSS. I can't find out how to write a code to change the first row and first column (header) colors and also change the color diagonally below from the top left.

I know that the table header can be changed by using `<th>` in CSS but I'm not sure how to use `<th>` in PHP. I did some research and the only solution for getting this multiplication table is below.

**NOTE nth-child() selector is not allowed.**

This is what my code looks like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <table border = "1">
            <?php
     
    $x = 1; //rows
    echo "<table border = '1'>\n";
     
    while ( $x <= 12 ) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
     
        $y = 1;//columns
        while ( $y <= 12 ) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$x x $y = " . $x * $y . "</td>\n";//the result of the multiplication
            $y++;
        }
     
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
        $x++;
    }
     
    echo "</table>";
     
    ?>
        </tr>
                </div>
            </table>
    </body>
```

CSS code as below.

```
    <style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
         font-family: arial, sans-serif;
         border-collapse: collapse;
    }
     tr{
        background-color: #FF8A65;
    }
    
    </style>
    </html>
```

And this is what it should look like:

[image: Table]

Comment: you need to use % for that, for example: `if($x % 10 == 0){ /*something*/ }`

Comment: _" can't find out how to write a code to change the first row and first column (header) colors"_ - well that would be all the cells, where either $x equals 1, or $y equals 1. _"and also change the color diagonally below from the top left"_ - and that would be those, where $x == $y.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>table</title>
    <style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
         font-family: arial, sans-serif;
         border-collapse: collapse;
    }
     tr{
        background-color: #82BFBF;
    }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <table border = "1">
<?php
     
    $x = 1; //rows
    echo "<table border = '1'>\n";
     
    while ( $x <= 12 ) {
        if ( $x == 1)
            echo "\t<tr style='background-color:green'>\n";
     
        $y = 1;
        while ( $y <= 12 ) {
            $bgc = '';
            if ( ($y == 1 || $x == 1) && $y != $x) {
                $bgc = "style='background-color:green'";
            } elseif ( $y == $x ) {
                $bgc = "style='background-color:red'";
            } elseif ($y > 1 && $x % 2){
                $bgc = "style='background-color:#FF8A65'";
            }
            echo "\t\t<td $bgc>$x x $y = " . $x * $y . "</td>\n";
            $y++;
        }
     
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
        $x++;
    }
     
    echo "</table>";
     
?>
    </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```